# Fazer submit com <a> e aparecer JS dialog

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

```
<form action="" name="Insert" method="post" onsubmit="alert(1);  return false;">


<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.Insert.submit()" type="submit" >Eliminar</a>
```

Boas pessoal, o que se passa é o seguinte, eu quando faço submit ele apenas faz o submit sem aparecer o alerta para confirmar, ja tentei de outra forma como:

```
<form action="" name="Insert" method="post" onsubmit="alert(1);  return false;">


<a href="#" onclick="alert(1);  return false; javascript:document.Insert.submit()" type="submit" >Eliminar</a>
```

Neste codigo que acabei de apresentar, apenas me aparece o dialogo, mas so consigo cancelar, eu ao clicar em "ok" ele nao faz nada, nem fecha o dialogo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você pretende fazer o submit e exibir o dialog, você terá que criar uma função em Js para controlar o submit do form ao clicar no link. Nessa ideia:

```
function submeteForm(){
alert("Foi submetido!!");
document.getElementById("Insert").submit();
}
```

Seu Form:

```
<form action="" name="Insert" id="Insert" method="post">
<a href="#" onclick="submeteForm()">Eliminar</a>
```

Agora se você só pretende exibir uma janela de confirmação, é mais simples ainda, basta adicionar no seu link:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('TEM CERTEZA?')" >Eliminar</a>
```

Comment: nao faz nada.. e estou a falar do seu primeiro exemplo que é oq preciso

Comment: Ja resolvi, mas no entanto so consegui graças assim, OBRIGADO